# Newest version of SafariDriver Cant Find Element Locations

Tags: selenium, safari, webdriver, webkit, safaridriver

In the newest version of SafariDriver that was shipped with Safari 12 I am seeing an issue where calling element.Location is throwing an error:

'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Of course this does not happen on Chrome or Firefox. What is strange is that I am able to execute click(), and SendKeys() without any issues. I would assume that both of those methods would need X and Y coordinates. Has anyone else run into this issue? I have a bug filed with Apple as well to look at the issue.